# I want my canvas object to appear in a popup

Tags: javascript, html

I am a beginner in JS programming. I have a class CanvasObjet which is functional (I tested it on my HTML) only I would like this canvas to appear in pop-up when we click on some buttons. I tried window.open () but it's not exactly what I want, and alert() returns my canvas in [HTMLCanvasElement]

```
class Formulaire {
constructor() {
reserv.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
//the function i need for a popup of canvas here
localStorage.setItem("nom",nom.value);
localStorage.setItem("prenom",prenom.value);
this.tempsRestant();
temps.textContent = "Lorem Ipsum" + prenom.value + "Lorem Ipsum " + nom.value;
})

class CanvasObjet {
constructor() {
this.canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
//Appelle l'interface CanvasRenderingContext2d
this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
this.ctx.strokeStyle = '#000000';
this.ctx.lineWidth = 3;
this.draw = false;
this.mousePosition = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
    };
this.lastPosition = this.mousePosition;
this.clearButton = document.getElementById("clear");
this.canvas.width = 300;
this.canvas.height = 300;
this.evenements();
};


<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

Comment: share all code, please! to assist you better!

Comment: okay, that's done ! thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Window.open opens something in a new tab.

If you want a pop up you will need to do this with css. But I suggest you use bootstrap for this, I use it all the time.

Take a look at the documentation for modals (pop ups): https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/modal/

I hope this helped.

Comment: hi thx for u suggest, I did not want to use bootstrap but I still learned and discovered modals jQuery, so thx to you